# Capitalization conventions for departments, schools, etc

Tags: writing-style, language

*(**Disclaimer:** I'm unsure if this is more appropriate here or on [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) instead; Please do migrate this if deemed more appropriate elsewhere)*

Are there any general guidelines on when/how to capitalize departmental names which are "pseudo-proper" names, e.g. *the department of applied stochastic basket-weaving science in the school of textile engineering at Dartmouth College*? — at least in terms of "grammar" (term used loosely here), the *the* in the example above seems enough: In this usage, it's understood there's only one department of applied stochastic basket-weaving science in the school of textile engineering at Dartmouth College, and there's only one school of textile engineering at Dartmouth College. However, in isolation, such names are often seen in ["title-ish" case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles):

> Department of Applied Stochastic Basket-Weaving Science

Likewise:

> School of Textile Engineering

However, would this style of case still be applicable when using these terms in running text?

> At the Department of Applied Stochastic Basket-Weaving Science (ASBWS) in the School of Textile Engineering at Dartmouth, methods have been developed for using the fibers from old baskets sitting on your grandmother's windowsill to create weapons for the battlefield of tomorrow.

This looks like A Lot of Unnecessary Capital Letters to me, but perhaps my judgement isn't correct.

Comment: Better on English.SE in my opinion.  Indeed, it was already asked and answered there: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74016/should-i-capitalize-chemical-engineering-department/74018#74018

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the capital letters apply to the words in the department name, even in running text.

The reason is because the whole department/faculty name contains all of those words. The department names are examples of [proper names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun#Proper_names).